# Difference between modules and existentials

Tags: module, ocaml, existential-type

It's folk knowledge that OCaml modules are "just" existential types. That there's some kind of parity between

```
module X = struct type t val x : t end
```

and

```
data 'a spec = { x : 'a }
data x = X : 'a spec
```

and this isn't untrue exactly.

But as I just evidenced, OCaml has both modules and existential types. My question is:

- How do they differ?
- Is there anything which can be implemented in one but not the other?
- When would you use one over the other (in particular comparing first-class modules with existential types)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Completing gsg's answer on your third point.

There are two kinds of way to use modules:

- As a structuring construct, when you declare toplevel modules. In that case you are not really manipulating existential variables. When encoding the module system in system-F, you would effectively represent the abstract types by existential variables, but morally, it is closer to a fresh singleton type.
- As a value, when using [first class modules](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/extn.html#sec230). In that case you are clearly manipulating existential types.

The other representations of existential types are through [GADT's](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/extn.html#sec238) and with objects. (It is also possible to encode existential as the negation of universal with records, but its usage are completely replaced by first class modules).

Choosing between those 3 cases depend a bit in the context.
If you want to provide a lot of functions for your type, you will prefer modules or objects. If only a few, you may find the syntax for modules or objects too heavywheight and prefer GADT. GADT's can also reveal a the structure of your type, for instance:

```
type _ ty =
  | List : ty -> ty list
  | Int : int list

type exist = E : 'a ty * 'a -> exist
```

If you are in that kind of case, you do not need to propagate the function working on that type, so you will end up with something a lot lighter with GADT's existentials. With modules this would look like

```
module type Exist = sig
  type t
  val t : t ty
end
module Int_list : Exist = struct
  type t = int list 
  let t = List Int
end
let int_list = (module Int_list:Exist)
```

And if you need sub-typing or late binding, go for the objects. This can often be encoded with modules but this tend to be tedious.

Answer (score 5):

It's specifically abstract types that have existential type. Modules without abstract types can be explained without existentials, I think.

Modules have features other than abstract types: they act as namespaces, they are structurally typed, they support operations like `include` and `module type of`, they allow private types, etc.

A notable difference is that functors allow ranging over types of any (fixed) arity, which is not possible with type variables because OCaml lacks higher kinded types:

```
module type M = sig
  type 'a t
  val x : 'a t
end
```

I'm not quite sure how to answer your last question. Modules and existentials are different enough in practice that the question of when to substitute one for the other hasn't come up.

Comment: It is not completely true that ocaml lacks higher kinded types. Some encoding are possible: http://www.lpw25.net/flops2014.pdf